# Is it possible to get key from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this

```
Array
    (
        [level] => sub_preschool
        [preschool] => preschool
        [primary] => 
        [secondary] => 
        [junior] => 
        [names] => 
    )
```

Now i want only that key which have value

i want key level,preschool

Comment: Which language? Looks like you want to use a Map anyway

Comment: Which language are you using? Plus an array normaly doesn't have keys, the structure you're describing is a dictionnary (or a hashmap).

Comment: I am getting this array in post

Comment: Have you read the PHP documentation about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)?

Comment: `$key = array_search($array, $value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) without supplying the `callback` parameter :

```
$result = array_filter($array);
```

> If no **callback** is supplied, all entries of **array** equal to **FALSE** (see [converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

**[Demo](http://3v4l.org/tLb9X)**